# Do the spinning parts of the tail mounted jet engines produce yaw on pitch changes?

Tags: jet-engine

For example: on takeoff at rotation, would the clockwise rotation of the 2 engines have enough force to move the nose of the aircraft left? Precession would be the force, is it strong enough?

Comment: One comment in that Q/A was semi pertinent to my question. It may be an answer, but I do not know.

Comment: Location of the engine (wing or tail) shouldn't make a difference in the yaw effect. The F4U Corsair, for example, needed rudder trim for takeoff with a propeller engine mounted in its _nose._ Everything said about jets in the linked question should apply to your tail-mounted engine as well.